# Python Spider: Extract info from list with partial match

Tags: python

I have a list of all the current tv models. As an example I'm using the Sony tv models. The official models look like this:

KDL40W705CBAEP 
KDL55W755CBAEP 
KD75XD8505BAEP 
KDL40WD650BAEP

With my script, see below, I managed to get everything match as long as the text on the webpage is a 100% match.

The issue I'm having is that some models are put on the website as followed

KDL40W705 CBAEP 
KDL55-W755 CBAEP 
KD75XD8505 
KDL40 WD650BAEP

How can I get those matched aswell?

```
import scrapy.selector 
import urlparse
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request
from MediaMarkt.items import MediamarktItem

models = []
for line in open("Sonytv.txt", "r"):
    models.append(line.strip("\n\-"))
d = {}
for model in models:
    d[model] = True

def complete_url(string):
    return "http://www.mediamarkt.de"+ string


def encode(str):
    return str.encode('utf8', 'ignore') 


class MshbeSpider(Spider):
    name = "mshdetv"
    start_urls = ['http://www.mediamarkt.de/mcs/productlist/_led-lcd-fernseher,48353,460668.html?langId=-3&searchParams=&sort=&view=&page=']

    def parse(self, response):  
        items = response.xpath('//ul[@class="products-list"]/li/div')
        for item in items:
            mshtv = MediamarktItem()
            mshtv['item_3_price'] = encode(item.xpath('normalize-space(.//aside/div/div/div/text())').extract()[0]).replace("-","")
            mshtv['item_2_name'] = encode(item.xpath('normalize-space(.//div/h2/a/text())').extract()[0])
            mshtv['item_a_link'] = item.select('.//div/h2/a/@href').extract()
            mshtv['item_4_avai'] = encode(item.xpath('normalize-space(.//aside/div/div/ul/li//text())').extract()[0])
            #mshtv['item_1_cat'] = encode(item.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="category"]/hgroup/h1/text())').extract()[0])
            for word in mshtv['item_2_name'].split(" "):
                if word in d:
                    mshtv['item_model'] = word            
            yield mshtv


        new_link = response.xpath('//li[@class="pagination-next"]/a/@href').extract()[0]
        yield Request(complete_url(new_link),callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: How does KDL40W705CBAEP etc.. fit into your code?

Comment: I have a text file were all the model references are in. I'm pulling the models form that list. The model numbers are displayed on the site as example 'TV SONY KD75XD8505BAEP 75" LCD EDGE LED Smart Ultra HD'. In this case I have a 100% match so no problem. But when its on the site as 'SONY KDL-55W805 CBAEP LED TV (Flat, 55 Zoll, Full-HD, 3D, SMART TV, Android TV)' than I have a problem as this isn't a 100% match

Comment: well there is not really enough in the text that you could even safely partially match, are you looking for particular models?

Comment: I've been playing around with adding .replace in the item_2_name field and that works a little bit but I'm looking for a 100% solution

Comment: Yes but there is not really enough to go on, if you had say just the same start or end strings you could match that but having arbitrary  matches all over the string does not give you the ability to match 100 percent as there is too much ambiguity, what from your file should match  `KDL-55W805 `?

Comment: KDL-55W805 needs to match KDL55W805CAEP. I found a partial solution by using ".replace("-","").replace(" C","C").replace(" B","B")". This helps me with KD-55W805 CAEP for example. The only one I'm still struggeling with is when there is no CAEP

Comment: Ah ok, that we can work with,  the start is always matching yes?

Comment: Not really it can be KDL55 or KDL-55 or KD55 or KD-55

Comment: So only the L can be missing? How about removing the L and - from both then using str.startswith